# Error : The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (String[])

Tags: android, textview

I'm a novice for android. I want to know the data of IMAGES.

But it show the error as

> The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (String[]) .

How to solve it?

**Code :**

```
TextView webContent = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
webContent.setText(IMAGES);
private final String[] IMAGES = Monsters_image.toArray(new String[Monsters_image.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `String` value in `TextView` and you directly set String `IMAGES` array to `TextView` which is wrong.

Set value in your `TextView` like

```
String[] IMAGES = Monsters_image.toArray(new String[Monsters_image.size()]);
webContent.setText(IMAGES[0]);
```

> What this does? It'll set first element of IMAGES array to your
>   TextView

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method that takes a `CharSequence` and trying to pass it an array of `Strings`. Clearly this will not work. Either give it just one String or change the way you show your data (a ListView perhaps?)